# I am trying to build a Multiple choice test in java and for some reason my code will only work for two questions and not anymore

Tags: java, swing

This is the code for my quiz.

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    public class Main2 {
        public class Questions {
            String Question;
            String userAns;
            String realAns;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Screen");
            frame.setSize(2500, 2500);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            panel.setSize(2500, 2500);
            panel.setLayout(null);  
            //panel.setBackground(Color.red);

            Question[] questions = new Question[2];
            System.out.println(questions.length);
            Question q1 = new Question();
            q1.Question = "1) What is your Name?";
            q1.A ="Bob";
            q1.B="Billy";
            q1.C="Joe";
            q1.D="Jill";
            questions[0] = q1;

            Question q2 = new Question();
            q2.Question = "2) What is your Age?";
            q2.A ="5";
            q2.B="69";
            q2.C="21";
            q2.D="12";
            questions[1] = q2;

            /*
            Question q3 = new Question();
            q3.Question = "3) When Is your Birthday?";
            q3.A = "May";
            q3.B="Jan";
            q3.C="Apr";
            q3.D="Aug";
            questions[2] = q3;
            */
            //When this question is added the code breaks down
            JLabel Question = new JLabel(questions[0].Question);
            Question.setBounds(50, 0, 1500, 50);
            panel.add(Question);
            Question.setFont(new Font(Question.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 25));
            Question.setVisible(true);

            JLabel incorrectAnswerLabel = new JLabel ("Incorrect Answer! Try Again");
            incorrectAnswerLabel.setBounds(300, 0, 1000, 500);
            panel.add(incorrectAnswerLabel);
            incorrectAnswerLabel.setVisible(false);
            incorrectAnswerLabel.setFont(new Font(incorrectAnswerLabel.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, 46));
            incorrectAnswerLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);

            JLabel correctAnswerLabel = new JLabel ("Correct Answer! Good Job");
            correctAnswerLabel.setBounds(300, 0, 1000, 500);
            panel.add(correctAnswerLabel);
            correctAnswerLabel.setVisible(false);
            correctAnswerLabel.setFont(new Font(correctAnswerLabel.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, 46));
            correctAnswerLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

            JButton submitButton = new JButton();
            submitButton.setBounds(50, 250, 150, 50);
            submitButton.setText("Submit");
            panel.add(submitButton);
            submitButton.setVisible(true);



            JRadioButton OptionA = new JRadioButton(questions[0].A);
            OptionA.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
            panel.add(OptionA);
            OptionA.setVisible(true);


            JRadioButton OptionB = new JRadioButton(questions[0].B);
            OptionB.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 50);
            panel.add(OptionB);
            OptionB.setVisible(true);

            JRadioButton OptionC = new JRadioButton(questions[0].C);
            OptionC.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 50);
            panel.add(OptionC);
            OptionC.setVisible(true);

            JRadioButton OptionD = new JRadioButton(questions[0].D);
            OptionD.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 50);
            panel.add(OptionD);
            OptionD.setVisible(true);



            ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            radioGroup.add(OptionA);
            radioGroup.add(OptionB);
            radioGroup.add(OptionC);
            radioGroup.add(OptionD);

            for(int i = 0; i < questions.length-1; i++)
            {
                final int count = i;
                submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        if(submitButton.getText().equals("Submit"))
                        {

                            if(OptionA.isSelected()) {
                                submitButton.setText("Next Question");
                                correctAnswerLabel.setVisible(true);

                            }   
                            else 
                                incorrectAnswerLabel.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            correctAnswerLabel.setVisible(false);
                            submitButton.setText("Submit");
                            Question q = questions[count+1];
                            Question.setText(q.Question);
                            setAnswers(q.A, q.B, q.C, q.D, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD);
                        }
                    }

                });
            }


        }

        static void setAnswers(String A, String B,String C,String D, JRadioButton a, JRadioButton b, JRadioButton c, JRadioButton d)
        {
            List<String> answers = Arrays.asList(A, B,C,D);
            Collections.shuffle(answers);
            a.setText(answers.get(0));
            b.setText(answers.get(1));
            c.setText(answers.get(2));
            d.setText(answers.get(3));
        }

    }
```

My code works fine with only two questions. When I add the third when in it doesn't even show the text for the problem. I tried debugging it to see if my code is still running. Seems to be that it does run. I worked for hours, but I in vain and desperately NEED help.

Notes:

- The Correct Answer will always be Option A (I didn't get as far as being able to get the right answer)
- The Submit Button is supposed to saySubmit AND Next Question. For some reason changing the questions array length to 3 makes it not do this

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, ..

Comment: .. or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: As specific advice: Given a quiz would imply questions (e.g. expressed in a `JLabel`) and a component to input the answer (e.g. a `JTextField`), a better approach would be to declare those as attributes of the class, then reuse those two components for *every* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main2 {

    public class Questions {

        String Question;
        String userAns;
        String realAns;
    }

    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Screen");
        frame.setSize(2500, 2500);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setSize(2500, 2500);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        //panel.setBackground(Color.red);

        Question[] questions = new Question[3];
        System.out.println(questions.length);
        Question q1 = new Question();
        q1.Question = "1) What is your Name?";
        q1.A = "Bob";
        q1.B = "Billy";
        q1.C = "Joe";
        q1.D = "Jill";
        questions[0] = q1;

        Question q2 = new Question();
        q2.Question = "2) What is your Age?";
        q2.A = "5";
        q2.B = "69";
        q2.C = "21";
        q2.D = "12";
        questions[1] = q2;

        Question q3 = new Question();
        q3.Question = "3) When Is your Birthday?";
        q3.A = "May";
        q3.B = "Jan";
        q3.C = "Apr";
        q3.D = "Aug";
        questions[2] = q3;

        //When this question is added the code breaks down
        JLabel Question = new JLabel(questions[0].Question);
        Question.setBounds(50, 0, 1500, 50);
        panel.add(Question);
        Question.setFont(new Font(Question.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 25));
        Question.setVisible(true);

        JLabel incorrectAnswerLabel = new JLabel("Incorrect Answer! Try Again");
        incorrectAnswerLabel.setBounds(300, 0, 1000, 500);
        panel.add(incorrectAnswerLabel);
        incorrectAnswerLabel.setVisible(false);
        incorrectAnswerLabel.setFont(new Font(incorrectAnswerLabel.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, 46));
        incorrectAnswerLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);

        JLabel correctAnswerLabel = new JLabel("Correct Answer! Good Job");
        correctAnswerLabel.setBounds(300, 0, 1000, 500);
        panel.add(correctAnswerLabel);
        correctAnswerLabel.setVisible(false);
        correctAnswerLabel.setFont(new Font(correctAnswerLabel.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, 46));
        correctAnswerLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

        JButton submitButton = new JButton();
        submitButton.setBounds(50, 250, 150, 50);
        submitButton.setText("Submit");
        panel.add(submitButton);
        submitButton.setVisible(true);

        JRadioButton OptionA = new JRadioButton(questions[0].A);
        OptionA.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
        panel.add(OptionA);
        OptionA.setVisible(true);

        JRadioButton OptionB = new JRadioButton(questions[0].B);
        OptionB.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 50);
        panel.add(OptionB);
        OptionB.setVisible(true);

        JRadioButton OptionC = new JRadioButton(questions[0].C);
        OptionC.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 50);
        panel.add(OptionC);
        OptionC.setVisible(true);

        JRadioButton OptionD = new JRadioButton(questions[0].D);
        OptionD.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 50);
        panel.add(OptionD);
        OptionD.setVisible(true);

        ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup.add(OptionA);
        radioGroup.add(OptionB);
        radioGroup.add(OptionC);
        radioGroup.add(OptionD);

        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (submitButton.getText().equals("Submit")) {

                    if (OptionA.isSelected()) {
                        submitButton.setText("Next Question");
                        correctAnswerLabel.setVisible(true);

                    } else {
                        incorrectAnswerLabel.setVisible(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    correctAnswerLabel.setVisible(false);
                    submitButton.setText("Submit");

                    if(count < questions.length-1){
                        count = count+1;
                    }
                    Question q = questions[count];
                    Question.setText(q.Question);
                    setAnswers(q.A, q.B, q.C, q.D, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD);
                }
            }

        });

    }

    static void setAnswers(String A, String B, String C, String D, JRadioButton a, JRadioButton b, JRadioButton c, JRadioButton d) {
        List<String> answers = Arrays.asList(A, B, C, D);
        Collections.shuffle(answers);
        a.setText(answers.get(0));
        b.setText(answers.get(1));
        c.setText(answers.get(2));
        d.setText(answers.get(3));
    }

}
```

Comment: The variable count is declared as a final int, so you can't say count = count + 1 right.

Comment: submitButton.addActionListener  button bind event one time.

Answer (score 0):

Array Index Starts from zero but the length starts from 1. The below will work if you want to add a 3rd question.

Question[] questions = new Question[3];

Arrays are not dynamic and hence if you want to add questions dynamically use an ArrayList. Otherwise increase the length of array to size you feel comfortable with.